Align down a photo to the div and maintain responsivity
I am asking for your help because I am having difficulties via css to handle this situation. My goal is to create via css something like this. Here is the link https://ibb.co/gd5Rccw.

I have tried to implement on codepen but I am having a hard time to handle then responsive.


.container {
       border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
       background-color: #789456;
       max-width: 1920px;
       height: 600px;
       position: relative;
       margin:auto;
      border-radius: 35px;
    }
    
.tag {
   float: left;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   z-index: 1000;
   background-color: #92AD40;
   padding: 5px;
   color: #FFFFFF;
   font-weight: bold;
}

h1 {
  position:absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
<div style="height:350px;"></div>
<div class="container">
       <img class="tag" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800">
       <h1>Title</h1>
</div>




You can use CSS Grid to align the items. Set align-self:end on the image so that if it overflows in height, it will overflow from the top side of the container.
Additionally, you need object-fit:contain if you want to maintain the image's aspect ratio while have it always occupy the left half of the container. Use percentage units or fr units for responsiveness.


.container {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  background-color: #789456;
  max-width: 1920px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 35px;
  display: grid;
  padding: 0 5rem;
  column-gap: 5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-auto-rows: 100%
}

.tag {
  background-color: #92AD40;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: end;
  object-fit: contain;
}

h1 {
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
}
<div style="height:350px;"></div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="tag" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>




In your case, container query is another way to handle responsiveness (especially since the ratios and container height are known). For example, if you think the (align end) layout looks undesirable when the screen width is too small for the image to overflow, you can use it to adjust the alignment:


.container {
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  background-color: #789456;
  max-width: 1920px;
  height: 600px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  border-radius: 35px;
  display: grid;
  padding: 0 5rem;
  column-gap: 5rem;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
  grid-auto-rows: 100%;
  container-type: size;
}

@container(max-width: 1198px) {
  .tag {
    align-self: center !important;
  }
}

.tag {
  background-color: #92AD40;
  padding: 5px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 100%;
  align-self: end;
  object-fit: contain;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

h1 {
  justify-self: start;
  align-self: center;
}
<div style="height:350px;"></div>
<div class="container">
  <img class="tag" src="http://www.placehold.it/800x800">
  <h1>Title</h1>
</div>



